# How to change the default location of the legend on a QChartView control

Tags: qt, pyqt, alignment, legend, qchart

I need to place the legend at the bottom of the chart (inside the colored box as per the print-screen attached) Any suggestions?

Also I want the legend to be displayed on the same line, but when I do, the text gets shrinked.

[image]

Comment: Explain better, the legend is part of QChartView. if you want to show something similar to the legend outside QChartView uses a label and places the information there.

Comment: yes the legend is a part of QchartView. I was avoiding the Label solution, because Legend is a good class, but if it is the unique solution I will do?

Comment: What do you mean by good class? How different is this class?

Comment: That offers functions that gets labels automatically, so I don't have to redefine them, and also the color is the same without redoing that, in fact that is more, a hope of using something standard in this part :p